# Fluid fixed block with left margin

Tags: css, css-position, fluid-layout

I need to put fixed block on the page. But it should be the fluid container's size (which have auto left-right margin) and left margin 160px inside container.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="header">Some fixed panel</div>
 Some other scrollable markup
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1280px;
 padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-width: 940px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;} 
#header { 
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 160px;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 60; }
```

And I can't make fixed panel to get correct width. Somehow this block get width not from container, but from window.

Need some solution without JS.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: use jsfiddle to show your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/only_dimon/5WcgC/18/

Made some changes to bring closer to the real project.
Fixed panel should be 100% width of the container minus left-margin

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used the fixed wrapper for the pannel with main container's margins and width.